# Can I fill the form fields in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

I have code to autofill form fields

```
(function( window ) {
    "use strict";
    var document = window.document,
        fieldValueMap = {
              "author"       : "author"
            , "name"        : "name"
            , "email"       : "email@gmail.com"
            , "url"         : "url.link"
            , "website"     : "website.com"
            , "comment"     : "comment"
            , "commentName"    : "commentName"
            , "commentEmail"  : "commentEmail@gmail.com"
            , "commentWebsite"   : "commentWebsite.com"
            , "commentComment"         : "commentComment"
        };
  
      Object.keys( fieldValueMap ).forEach(function( name ){
  
          var input = document.querySelector( "form input[id='" + name + "']" )
                          || document.querySelector( "form select[id='" + name + "']" )
              || document.querySelector( "form textarea[id='" + name + "']" );
  
          input && input.type !== "hidden" && ( input.value = fieldValueMap[ name ] );
      });
  
  })(window);
```

But it doesn't work properly when there is iframe on the website page.
It works only when I'm manually choosing "evaluation context" and put the code in console.
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUuPk.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Ewx.png)

So I wonder if there is a way to automatize the process of filling forms in iframe and make the whole script work together.
Perfectly I'd like to use final script as a bookmarklet.
My first coding experience, found the code on the internet and customized it for my needs. I'm sorry if the question is too stupid.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: To get element by ID use `document.getElementById()`. To access iframe's content follow above comment. Code will be something like this: `iframeElement.contentDocument.getElementById()`